# How to convert an image stream to an img elements src?

Tags: javascript, image, binary, base64

I'm receiving what I am assuming to be a jpeg image stream from a request. I want to turn this into something usable as am image elements source. I've tried many methods but I continue to get an invalid preview image.

This is what it looks like:

```
����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u000........
```

It has many strange symbols throughout the string.

[image: Response]

I've tried converting to base64 which did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those sybols are only visual code view of binary data. Please refer to link below , to resolve your problem:

[https://logfetch.com/js-image-binary-jfif](https://logfetch.com/js-image-binary-jfif/)

```
fetch(API_URL)
  .then(resp => resp.data.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.getElementById("preview").src = url;
  });
```